# Working on arrays in PHP

Tags: php

Assuming that you have three arrays which might contain different values as follows.:

```
$arr1 = array('1', '5', '10');
$arr2 = array('1', '3', '10');
$arr3 = array('1', '6', '10');
```

How would you strip out what's different and get it as follows?:

```
$arr1 = array('1', '10');
$arr2 = array('1', '10');
$arr3 = array('1', '10');
```

---

I meant I wanted to get it as follows.:

```
$result = array('1', '10');
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('1', '5', '10');
$arr2 = array('1', '3', '10');
$arr3 = array('1', '6', '10');

$result = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);

print_r($result);

//now assign it back:
$arr1 = $result;
$arr2 = $result;
$arr3 = $result;
?>
```